# A reflexive subspace is weak* closed in the bidual.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $Y$ be a closed subspace. I am working on an exercise for which the hint reads:

> If $Y$ is reflexive, $Y$ is weak* closed in $X^{**}$.

Can anybody explain why the statement is is true? Thanks.

Comment: Can you spell out what does 'weak*-closed' mean, maybe that brings you closer to the solution..

Comment: I think it means that $Y$ is closed in the weak topology on $X^{**}$ with respect to evaluations at points in $X^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to see it is the closed range theorem. The restriction $\varrho \colon X^\ast \to Y^\ast$ is surjective, in particular has closed range, hence the range of its transpose $\varrho^\ast \colon Y^{\ast\ast} \to X^{\ast\ast}$ is weak*-closed.

Since $Y$ is reflexive, the canonical embedding $J_Y \colon Y \to Y^{\ast\ast}$ is surjective, and it's easily verified that $\varrho^\ast \circ J_Y$ is the canonical embedding of $Y$ into $X^{\ast\ast}$.